# How to repeat a random number method in a loop until true on Java?

Tags: java

The method pricee() returns the double "sum" which is a random number. I want this random number to keep changing until it is less than 10.

However, the loop only runs once and prints out 'sum' if true but gives an error if false. How do I call this method until the random number sum becomes less than 10?

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Menu_algorithm {
    private static int[] anArray;
    private static double sum = 0;
    private static double monPrice;
    private static double tuePrice;
    private static double wedPrice;
    private static double thuPrice;
    private static double friPrice;
    private static double satPrice;
    private static double sunPrice;
    private static double[] prices = {1.25,3.10,1.78,2.1,1.76,2.12,1.43,1.22,0.11,0.32,0.42,0.66,0.74,2.22};

    public static int[] randList() {
        anArray = new int[7];
        for(int i=0;i<anArray.length;i++){
            anArray[i] = randomFill();
        }
        return anArray;
    }

    public static double pricee(){
        randList();
        monPrice = prices[anArray[0]];
        tuePrice = prices[anArray[1]];
        wedPrice = prices[anArray[2]];
        thuPrice = prices[anArray[3]];
        friPrice = prices[anArray[4]];
        satPrice = prices[anArray[5]];
        sunPrice = prices[anArray[6]];
        sum = monPrice + tuePrice + wedPrice + thuPrice + friPrice + satPrice + sunPrice;
        return sum;
    }

    public static void pCheck(){
        while (true){
            pricee();
            if (sum < 10){
                System.out.print(sum);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static int randomFill(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt(15);
        return randomNum;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        pCheck();
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (sum < 10) pricee();`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Didn't you mean `while (sum >= 10)`?

Comment: This code doesn't appear to be thread safe.  Since we can't see the source for the method that returns sum, it's impossible to say if the issue lies there or not.

Comment: The condition doesn't necessarily need to be in the `while (...)`. The current approach would work too. The key problem probably is the **reversed logic**.

Comment: Also, if `pricee` "returns" sum, then it should probably be `double sum = pricee()`

Comment: Please create a [mcve], in particular include the `pricee` method.

Comment: As of now the question is unclear.

Comment: @tobias_k Yes. I read it as "at least 10".

Comment: The only problem seems to be an occasional array index out of bounds error when you roll a `14` to index into your array of `14` elements. Apart from that, it seems to work fine. But getting a price higher than 10 is pretty rare, so a single iteration is rather normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function pricee() causes problems. It's because you get element that way:

```
prices[anArray[6]];
```

It means that if your randomFill() function return 14 and insert it into anArray you will try to get 14 element from prices list which contains 14 elements so the index of last element is 13 and the program throws IndexOutOfBoundException

In function randomFill() replace

```
int randomNum = rand.nextInt(15);
```

To:

```
int randomNum = rand.nextInt(prices.length);
```

Comment: Instead of `rand.nextInt(14)` I'd rather suggest `rand.nextInt(prices.length)`

Comment: That's right because if when element will be deleted from that list there will be exception again